# Автозаполнение Java в Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

Установил идею ультимейт, не работает автозаполнение. Для примера написал:

```java
BufferedReader Reader = new
```

И после этого на старой идее, которая была на комьюнити  автоматически были показаны классы, которые можно добавить, например сразу выскакивало окно, в котором можно добавить `BufferedReader()` и т.п. классы. Сейчас такого нет.